# Search keys in Map

Tags: java, search, sortedmap

I use SortedMap to save mappings between String keys and ArrayList for value. Keys are simple strings consisting of several words. I want to get all entries where key matches to a query.

So if I have following mappings:

```
"A B C D E" => ArrayList("hello","hi","howdy")
"A C B"  => ArrayList("hehe","haha","hihi") 
"C B E" => ArrayList("non", "sense")
```

and I query for "A C" I get back both entries corresponding "A B C D E" and "A C B", with corresponding similarity coefficients (0.4 and 0.66).

My idea was to iterate through all keys with .keySet(). Then I split the query into separate Strigns with query.split(" ") and recursively limit list of matches but I am not sure if that is the optimal way to do things and if there might not be already existing "search engine" implemented in Java.

My scratch:

```
public HashMap<String,Double> searchTags(String query) {

    HashMap<String,Double> hash = new HashMap<String,Double>();

    double similarity = 0;

    //split tags
    String[] tags = query.split(" ");

    for (String key : this.tagsToUtterance.keySet()) {
        for (String tag : tags) {
            if (key.contains(tag)) {
                System.out.println("ok");
                hash.put(key,similarity);
                similarity =+1 ;
            }
        }
        similarity = similarity/key.split(" ").length;
    }

    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Well that solution seems pretty inefficient. You could implement a custom data structure, where you use Maps?

Comment: if there is `B C X A` key, for a `A C` search , should it be in your result?

Comment: Kent: yes it should be in the result as well

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is keep a Multimap for your keys ("A", "C", etc...) to the mapping "A B C D E", retrieve for each search term all mappings and calculate the intersection of all search term sets. Like this:

```
Set<SearchMap> getMappings(List<String> searchTerms) {
    Set<SearchMap> result = this.getSearchMapForTerm(searchTerms.get(0));

    for(int i=1;i< searchTerms.size(); i++) {
        Sets.intersection(result, this.getSearchMapForTerm(searchTerms.get(i)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Have a look at the guava collections API: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained

That would be just a quick and dirty solution. (add the boundary checks etc...)

Answer (score 0):

This method should do the work for you:

```
private Map<Double, Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>> queryMethod(
            Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map, String queryString) {
        Map<Double, Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>> result = new HashMap<Double, Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>>();
        queryString = queryString.replaceAll(" ", "");

        for (Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey().replaceAll(" ", "");
            boolean contained = true;

            for (char c : queryString.toCharArray()) {
                if (key.indexOf(c) < 0) {
                    contained = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (contained) {
                double percent = (double) queryString.length()
                        / (double) key.length();
                result.put(new Double(percent), entry);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Call the method with your SortedMap with the String-ArrayList pairs and the string you are willing to do the search for and it will return a Map, containing the percents + the corresponding entries in your original Map.